# Possible to have multiple crowd-classifier elements in mturk?

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is it possible to have two crowd-classifier elements? I tried the follow, for example, but it just duplicates the form and results in two submissions buttons. How do I make it so that there is only one submission button and one set of instructions/shortcuts?

```
<crowd-form>
    
    <crowd-classifier
      name="category"
      categories="['Optimism', 'Neutral', 'Other']"
      header="Select the relevant categories"
    >
        <classification-target> ${text} </classification-target>
    </crowd-classifier>
   
    <crowd-classifier-multi-select
      name="category"
      categories="['Admiration', 'Gratitude', 'Curiousity', 'Optimism', 'Neutral', 'Other']"
      header="Select the relevant categories"
      exclusion-category="{ text: 'None of the above' }"
    >
        <classification-target> ${text} </classification-target>
    </crowd-classifier-multi-select>
</crowd-form>
```

[image]